# NSUserDefaults Not Saving TextField Text (Swift)

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to create a game with Swift, and I want to add the ability to create a username, which will be saved in NSUserDefaults. This is my code:

```
println("Textfield Text: \(usernameTextfield.text)")

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(usernameTextfield.text, forKey:"Username")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username") as? String)
```

The output is:

> Textfield Text: MyUsername
>
> nil

The only explanation I can see as to why it is printing nil is that either the saving or the loading of the username is failing. Is there any way this can be corrected or am I doing something wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Replace `username` when you save it with a string literal. See if you get the same results.

Comment: what is the variable "username"? make sure it doesn't copy any nil values, and I would go with `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(usernameTextfield.text, forKey:"Username")` instead.

Comment: username was declared earlier in the code as: var username = usernameTextfield.text;

Comment: I had to do `textfield.text!` to get the unwrapped value out for unit tests. May need to unwrap the value

Comment: Where in my code do I put the exclamation mark? (After the `.text` on line 2 gave an error).

Comment: @68cherries No, when I replace `usernameTextfield.text` on line 2 with a literal, the second `println()` works fine.

Comment: @nanothread59 that would suggest that something is going wrong with the text input and `usernameTextfield.text` is nil. Could you include the relevant code for the text input?

Comment: Ahh... Just swapped the `usernameTextfield.resignFirstResponder()` from after the save to before. Works perfectly now. Thanks for that comment - it got me thinking!

Comment: Note `synchronize()` is no longer needed and its use is discouraged by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_10UserDefaults

Answer (score 8):

```
println("Textfield Text: \(usernameTextfield.text)")

var myValue:NSString = usernameTextfield.text

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myValue, forKey:"Username")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

var myOutput: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username")
println(myOutput)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In Swift 4.1

 UserDefaults.standard.set(textfield.text, forKey: "yourKey") // saves text field text
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

// To Retrieve
textfield.text = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"yourKey") as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small modification to Roman's answer with Swift 2.0 and Xcode 6.4.

**saving:**

```
    var myValue:NSString = usernameTF.text

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myValue, forKey:"Username")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**retrieving:**

```
var myOutput = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Username")
if (myOutput != nil)
{
    self.title = "Welcome "+((myOutput) as! String)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0

```
    let userDefult = UserDefaults.standard //returns shared defaults object.

    if let userName = usernameTextfield.text {
        //storing string in UserDefaults
        userDefult.set(userName, forKey: "userName") //Sets the value of the specified default key in the standard application domain.
    }

    print(userDefult.string(forKey: "userName")!)//Returns the string associated with the specified key.
```

Comment: I executed this code on my xcode 8. it working fine. still why it is down voted. please feel free to comment so i can improve myself.

Answer (score 0):

For swift 3.0, You can create user default by,

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yourValue", forKey: "YourString")
```

To Print the value in console :

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "YourString")!)
```